# How to pass view model class argument when call block from static block

Tags: magento2, viewmodel

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
<arguments>
<argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
```

I just want to call the above block via **Static block** (From Admin), but it gives an error due to **ViewModel** class.

I don't know **how to pass view model argument when we call block via static block**

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set object as arguments when using the Markup Notation in Magento2.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" view_model="Vendor\Example\ViewModel\Standard" name="Vendor_Example::view.phtml" }}
```

## In view.phtml

If you execute echo $block->getViewModel() will return **Vendor\Example\ViewModel\Standard** as a string and not an object.